# Which firearms should a group of people time-travelling with the intent to conquer carry if it's a one way trip on a ship

Tags: time-travel, firearms, guns

So, recently I've been recently reading Chinese web novels where a group of people travel to the past in a ship. Some of these novels have travelers' ships stranded in time while others find a portal and prepare things and travel. I read these by mtl ing them using Google translate.

Warning for those trying to find these novels: Chinese web novels have an extreme amount of racism and the characters exhibit very authoritarian tendencies. Don't expect the characters to go spreading democracy.

**If a group of time travelers were preparing to embark on a one way trip to the past on a ship, which firearms should they take? And for the time they're going to travel to, it can be any time before 1765.**

The  bullets they can carry are limited and any guns they should take should make good use of every shot.  For example, killing the enemy leaders from far away might easily win them the war even before it's fought. Guns which use traditional gun powder and for which bullets can be made in the past should be good. Like rifled cannons and rifled muskets. Also rifled minie ball guns? Minie balls should be easy to make, right?

They are eventually going to start the industrial revolution and make their own guns, but they'll have to survive until them and not run out of bullets.

Even recommendations for not too big machines related to firearms and bullets are welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've changed it a bit and put the main point in bold

Comment: You need to tell us the group size and carrying capacity of their time machine. Big difference beween 5 people and just what they can carry in backpacks, and 100 people who can take a container with them

Comment: VTC:Too Story-Based. What tools or skills any time traveler should take with them (the question has been attempted on the Stack many times before) is wholly a question of [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609) and has nothing to do with worldbuilding. There is no "best" in any context other than the needs of your story.

Comment: They travel on a ship which is going to travel through a portal

Comment: Also, the question is going to help time travel authors and role players so, it should be allowed even though it isn't perfect

Comment: @CityLord That's not how Stack Exchange works. We've never allowed this kind of question. The [help/on-topic] specifically states that we are here to help you build your world, not to tell your story. Please think this through. Whatever answers you might get will only be based on story conditions you provide. Those story conditions are unique to you and are not particularly beneficial to anyone else. Any weapon of any type can be rationalized given a story context. There is no best weapon, only the weapon you choose and the story you tell to use it.

Comment: Guns, meh. If you're having to shoot people, one at a time, you're probably doing it wrong. It isn't 1914 anymore! A big boxful of small drones capable of carrying and dropping small objects, solar chargers and spare parts seems much more practical.

Comment: I would echo the Starfish here, taking guns with you isnt super useful on its own. If anything you would want to bring the capability to make more guns, or really ordinance. A single modern drone with a ground crew, lots of spare parts, supplies etc. could probably single handedly win any war of this period. In large part because power is so centralized. At war with Catharine the Great ? Not under my watch, *blows up idk Petrograd or whever she was*

Comment: The real question is how much ammunition they can carry, and what they need to take with them to make more ammunition. For any army ever, ammunition is the real heavy lift; weapons are lightweight by comparison. Modern smokeless powder simply cannot be made before 1800, so to make more they will need to develop a chemical industry, and that will take a lot of time. Modern primers would also be a very complicated problem before 1700 or so.

Comment: P.S. They had field cannon and heavy cavalry in the 18th century. A small-ish group of infantry, say up to battalion size, would be very quickly defeated by any self-respecting 18th century army, no matter what kind of man-portable weapons they have. Bringing machine guns would allow them to win a few battles, but then when the ammunition runs out they cannot make any more, and the locals would be rather angry at them... Their best bet, if they can choose their destination, is to go to California and bootstrap an industrial civilization far away.

Comment: You probably want to carry as much modern guns with modern ammo as you can for maximum effectiveness for important engagements and then at the rear end carry the older firearms where you can produce ammo on site for the long haul. Might as well throw in a few tanks of nerve gas while you're at it too.

Comment: It won't matter what weapons they use, as the inevitable (and tedious) time-travel paradoxes will cancel out anything they do. You could have a lot more fun with *that* story.

Answer (score 2):

There are different answers for a single time traveler with a backpack and for a group with the payload of a ship. The group should carry a mix, presuming the **can** get all of them legally or illegally:

- A number of scoped, bolt-action rifles around 7.62mm NATO and a good supply of match-quality bullets. Both hunting and sniping with the goal of *one shot, one kill.* Alternatively semiautomatic rifles in this caliber, like the [L1A1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L1A1_Self-Loading_Rifle).
- A number of GPMGs around 7.62mm NATO and a good supply of belted ammo. These are for a last-ditch defense against human wave attacks, and it should be possible to pull bullets from the belts for use with the rifles even if they are not match quality.
- A number of semiautomatic pistols in 9mm and a good supply of ammo *and magazines*. For self-defense in closed quarters or by individuals.
- A number of [caplock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percussion_cap), black powder revolvers with molds for the bullets and a **really large** number of percussion caps. The idea is that they will ultimately produce new caps, but for starters all they have to find are lead and the ingredients of black powder.
- A number of single-shot, metallic-cartridge, black powder rifles like the [Martini-Henry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martini%E2%80%93Henry), with molds for bullets and the tools to reload the cartridges with black powder and percussion caps. Perhaps a hundred cartridges per gun, and several thousand caps per gun.

Only one model in each category, so that spare parts are interchangeable.

The 9mm are included in addition to the revolvers because a modern gun is much less finicky than a caplock. A few emissaries at the court of a native ruler might be able to shoot their way out. If capacity is limited and there must be a choice, the revolvers probably win.

The single-shot rifle is included because ammunition can be mostly replenished locally. Assign each shooter a native assistant with orders to collect the empties for refurbishing. Assuming that the natives know black powder, and become used to the black powder rifles in action, the first use of the MGs will be a shock effect.

Or the GPMGs *and* the 9mm might be swapped for a supply of AK-style rifles, but that would mean they use different ammo from the scoped rifles.

I presume you are already thinking of the usual "force multipliers" for time-traveling invaders, like radios, camera drones, and ultralight aircraft.

Answer (score 0):

There are a *lot* of options possible and the question really does come down to how much Ammo can you take - For example - At the moment - I've got probably about ~500 .22lr, ~100 rounds of .308, ~40 rounds of .303 and ~40 rounds of .44 Magnum - To put that in perspective - that all fits rather nicely in a lockable compartment in my gun safe: [which is similar to this one here](https://www.outdoorsupplies.co.nz/Stealth_5GunSafe.html#:%7E:text=Gunsafe%20Page&text=The%20Stealth%20A%2DCat%205,bolt%20mainlock%20has%207%20levers.)

As you'll note - that's not that big. So when you say 'Ammunition is limited' - I know competition shooters who will *carry* several boxes of Ammo to the range, and that's several thousand rounds of Ammo.

[PewPew Tactical has this article on suggested Ammo stockpiles](https://www.pewpewtactical.com/ammo-equation/)

Which says 1,500 per defensive handgun, per family member.
2,000 for each type of Semi-Auto, intermediate cartridge (ARs, AKs etc.).
500 per Hunting rifle calibre.
250-500 for Slug/Buckshot for Shotguns.
1000 for Birdshot for Shotguns
250 for anything else that isn't a common calibre that you use.

The closing line though is important - for a regular shooter, having a stockpile of 5,000-10,000 rounds is recommended.

If I'm on a Ship (and not humping it in the field) - I'm probably going to be taking something in that order of Magnitude.

**Right, now that we've set a baseline for what constitutes 'How much Ammo' - to answer the question**

Firstly -although O.M. has written a good answer - I'm going to disagree with it - That is - having multiple firearms in multiple calibres is extra weight. A case could be made for a semi-auto sidearm for personal defense - however - if you are engaging in a pistol fight, something has gone seriously wrong - and you can get a brace of Flintlock pistols in your time period, so I'd just use those.

So for my answer, we are restricting ourselves to a Single Firearm type and a single calibre.

Next element to consider is where you are going to be going - since a rifle won't just be for Combat - but also Food/Hunting and defense against Wildlife.

This leads us to realistically 3 options - and no surprises, they are the most boring options (but they are that way for a reason):

**Option 1 - An AR pattern rifle in 5.56**

The AR is the current gold standard *for a reason* - want a short one for CQB? No problem. Want a standard Rifle for general purpose infantry? No problem. Want a setup capable of reaching out past 400 metres? No problem. Want to harvest most medium sized Game? No Problem.

The 5.56 round is good enough to do just about everything. Light recoil, relatively light weight, effective out to 400 metres (but as above, with tinkering can be streteched - people can and do take it out to just under 1,000 metres).

The ARs modularity means you could have a single lower with a nice matchgrade trigger and a couple of Uppers (okay, this is kinda breaking my single gun rule - but my answer, my rules) - one for hunting, one for longer ranges, one for CQB.

The advantage is that with the 5.56 round and a modern optic - you are going to outrange everyone on the battlefield by several hundred metres. You are compromising a bit of stopping power for carrying more ammo by weight.

**Option 2 a Semi-Automatic rifle in a full-power Rifle Calibre**

Most likely going to be an AR-10 variant, but could also go for something like an H&K 417. Probably chambered in .308/7.62 NATO, but could use something like 6.5 Creedmore (I have a personal bias toward .308)

This would be my choice if I was going somewhere that had bigger Game - like Bears or Moose or larger Deer and if the engagement distances were much more open.

Again with an AR pattern rifle as the interchangeable uppers really allows you to customize for what you are doing. The advantage here is that at the longer ranges, the .308 or similar has more power, with a modern Semi-Auto rifle, properly setup - you could reliably take 800 metre shots, whilst still being able to use it in close-quarters if SHTF.

Other options - FN-FAL (or modern variant), SCAR-H, M1A variant, HK 417 as referenced, DesertTech MDR etc.

**A Semi-Automatic Rifle in a Gucci Calibre**

What do I mean by a Gucci Calibre - I mean something that isn't a common calibre. So for example .270 British (AKA the original EM2 calibre), .277 Fury (The calibre of the NSGW/XM7) etc.

Essentially the same reasoning for the above rifles - but these Calibres are trying to find a compromise between the 7.62 and other full-power cartridges and 5.56 and other intermediate cartridges - trying to have the range and stopping power of the larger calibre, but the weight and recoil of a smaller calibre. But in practice finding that as a compromise they don't really excel at either.

Add to that that Ammunition in these calibres tends to be expensive, since it's not mass-produced for the Military and so these firearms/calibres tend not to see widespread use. For most people it is cheaper to have a rifle in 5.56 and 7.62 and pay those prices for Ammo, than it is to have something in an exotic calibre that can fill both roles - but if that isn't a concern, then it would probably be a good option.

**The one option made conspicuous by it's absence... Why no FunSwitch?**

Why am I not advocating for anything full auto? Well - I was tempted - I mean, a Minigun in 7.62, even with the Ammunition/power limitations is a massively scary weapon - but we have to put this into perspective:

Full Auto fire is great at suppressing your opponents, even if they have Full auto capability themselves...

**But against people who aren't armed with repeating firearms, it's massively overkill**

Fast follow-up shots with a Semi-Auto is more than suppressive enough when all you've got is a single shot blackpowder firearm - in the ~20 seconds it takes you to reload, I've already sent 30, **aimed** shots downrange - Full Auto is just not necessary when your opponent doesn't have a repeating Firearm (Lever action, Revolver, Bolt action etc.)

Comment: Two related questions here. First, how practical is it to set up ammo production for the types you mention? That was a huge factor in my suggestions. Second, I find the stockpile suggestions insanely high for the real world, unless one is training a lot, and shopping wholesale (or a survivalist nutcase), but insufficient for a one-way time travel scenario. Properly trained shooters should expend hundreds of bullets *per person, per weapon type,* every year on refresher training, That will run through the reserves in a few years.

Comment: @o.m. On the first question - assuming you had an adequate supply of smokeless powder, projectiles, brass and primers - easy. The issue is that with 1700s level of manufacturing, you won't have the tolerances to produce ammunition. As for Ammo levels - It depends on the individual. The amounts given I would say skew towards the serious shooter or one who wishes to be proficient with a firearm in a self-defense scenario (it's a US site afterall)

Comment: @o.m. - as an Aside, in NZ, our Firearm certified police I believe were allocated a training budget of 200 rounds a year. There are competitive shooters at my local club who will do that (and more) in a single afternoon. It really does depend a lot.

Comment: I'm not in the US, but I can't see any self-defense situation using up a thousand rounds even there. That sounds more like the stock of a sports shooter who trains every other week, and goes shopping once a quarter. Here in Germany it takes a license to own a firearm, and licensed sports shooters must train regularly to justify their license. A dozen times a year or so.

Comment: @o.m. I think you missed what I meant - thousands of rounds is to become proficient in the event of a self-defense scenario - e.g. training. The actual event would likely not go past a few magazines worth of ammo.

Answer (score -1):

If they were smart they could easily do it on a budget and target somewhere like America which was basically using wood, teeth and stone weapons. The Spaniards took over from the Aztecs with just a few hundred men.

A few machine guns would suffice, and boom you're a race of gods with millions of worker bees at your disposal and an organised Empire of people to kick start your industrial revolution. Assuming your people have the scientific know how, you'd be expanding into the rest of the World well within 50 years with planes and tanks and walking through any opposition.

Or just go to an earlier timeframe in the Middle East, China, India or anywhere with an Imperial infrastructure worth taking over. It will save a lot of effort if the infrastructure is in place already and transport etc,. are already figured out with a workforce already used to changes in rulers.

You don't even have to beat their armies, just target the rulers direct and take over the capital and prove you can hold it and you'll soon have armies signing up to do your dirty work for you.

Comment: Honestly, a more likely outcome is "_overconfident gun-fetishists die of infection contracted from accidental injury_". The population of the americas is likely to be rather more challenging to topple when it isn't being ravaged by highly communicable diseases that time travellers are unlikely to bring with them, and subduing a nation without the aid of reinforcements will be something of a challenge, especially if you brought more snipers than linguists with you...

Comment: To double down on @StarfishPrime's comment, the Aztecs were reeling from the loss of 40% of their population to smallpox when the Spaniards "took over".  And arquebuses were barely necessary, as the _other_ diseases continued to run rampant through the population.  Hard to establish a counter-force when bodies choke the streets.

Comment: @jdunlop you chaps seem to be fixated on this, so I won't argue. Suit yourselves... or read what actually happened and discount the fluff, whichever you want

Comment: @Kilisi: Cortez took the Aztec Empire with a about 1,300 Spaniards *and many tens of thousands of [Tlaxcalans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tlaxcaltec)*. The Tlaxcalans were not happy with their Aztec overlords and became allies of the Spaniards, and in exchange for their help they got to maintain their autonomy in post-conquest Mexico and to be considered equal to the Spaniards in all respects. They maintained this privileged status up to the end of Spanish colonial rule; even today, the Free and Sovereign State of Tlaxcala is one of states comprising the United Mexican States.